# ¿Por qué mi página web se sale hacía arriba?

Tags: html, css, web, scroll

Durante estos días que llevo haciendo mi página web, he comprobado que algunos textos y vídeos se van hacía arriba (se salen y no se puede hacer scroll). Me gustaría saber si se puede hacer que el primer texto aparezca en el medio de la pantalla y luego al hacer scroll se vaya subiendo (como un scroll normal).

Os dejo una captura que espero que os sirva de algo. (¡Lo blanco no es tema de la página web!)
[image: Página Web "defectuosa"]

Código HTML y CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    background-color: #1f2029;
    overflow: scroll;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1462889/pat-back.svg');
  background-position: fixed;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 4%;
  scrollbar-width: thin;          /* "auto" or "thin" */
  scrollbar-color: transparent;   /* scroll thumb and track */
}
.section-center{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}





/* Textos */

h1{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 7vw;
  line-height: 10;
  color: #ff0000; /* #ffeba7; */ 
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #ff4242;
  text-stroke: 2px #ff7070;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

h2{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 7vw;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ff0000; /* #ffeba7; */ 
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #ff4242;
  text-stroke: 2px #ff7070;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

h3{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 5vw;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #34d6fe; /* #ffeba7; */ 
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #00ccff;
  text-stroke: 2px #00a7d1;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}





[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked){
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.menu-icon:checked + label,
.menu-icon:not(:checked) + label{
  position: fixed;
  top: 63px;
  right: 75px;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu-icon:checked + label:before,
.menu-icon:not(:checked) + label:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #ececee;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ececee;
  transition: border-width 100ms 1500ms ease, 
              top 100ms 1600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),
              height 100ms 1600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), 
              background-color 200ms ease,
              transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.menu-icon:checked + label:after,
.menu-icon:not(:checked) + label:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 10px;
  right: 4px;
  background-color: #ececee;
  margin-top: -1px;
  transition: width 100ms 1750ms ease, 
              right 100ms 1750ms ease,
              margin-top 100ms ease, 
              transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.menu-icon:checked + label:before{
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ececee;
  border-width: 0;
  transition: border-width 100ms 340ms ease, 
              top 100ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),
              height 100ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), 
              background-color 200ms 500ms ease,
              transform 200ms 1700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.menu-icon:checked + label:after{
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: width 100ms ease,
              right 100ms ease,  
              margin-top 100ms 500ms ease, 
              transform 200ms 1700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 33px;
  right: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: #353746;
  animation: border-transform 7s linear infinite;
  transition: top 350ms 1100ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),  
              right 350ms 1100ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),
              transform 250ms 1100ms ease,
              width 650ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),
              height 650ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
u/keyframes border-transform{
    0%,100% { border-radius: 63% 37% 54% 46% / 55% 48% 52% 45%; } 
  14% { border-radius: 40% 60% 54% 46% / 49% 60% 40% 51%; } 
  28% { border-radius: 54% 46% 38% 62% / 49% 70% 30% 51%; } 
  42% { border-radius: 61% 39% 55% 45% / 61% 38% 62% 39%; } 
  56% { border-radius: 61% 39% 67% 33% / 70% 50% 50% 30%; } 
  70% { border-radius: 50% 50% 34% 66% / 56% 68% 32% 44%; } 
  84% { border-radius: 46% 54% 50% 50% / 35% 61% 39% 65%; } 
}

.menu-icon:checked ~ .nav {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  transition: top 350ms 700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),  
              right 350ms 700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),
              transform 250ms 700ms ease,
              width 750ms 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),
              height 750ms 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.nav ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.nav ul li:nth-child(1){
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.nav ul li:nth-child(2){
  transition-delay: 150ms;
}
.nav ul li:nth-child(3){
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
.nav ul li:nth-child(4){
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}
.nav ul li a{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9vh;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #ececee;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffeba7;
}
.nav ul li a:after{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  content: '';
  height: 2vh;
  margin-top: -1vh;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #353746;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: width 250ms linear;
}
.nav ul li a:hover:after{
  width: 100%;
}


.menu-icon:checked ~ .nav  ul li {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: opacity 350ms ease,
              transform 250ms ease;
}
.menu-icon:checked ~ .nav ul li:nth-child(1){
  transition-delay: 1400ms;
}
.menu-icon:checked ~ .nav ul li:nth-child(2){
  transition-delay: 1480ms;
}
.menu-icon:checked ~ .nav ul li:nth-child(3){
  transition-delay: 1560ms;
}
.menu-icon:checked ~ .nav ul li:nth-child(4){
  transition-delay: 1640ms;
}



.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 50px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 11;
    transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.logo img {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}



u/media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .menu-icon:checked + label,
  .menu-icon:not(:checked) + label{
    right: 55px;
  }
  .logo {
    left: 30px;
  }
  .nav{
    right: 30px;
  }
  h1{
    font-size: 9vw;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px transparent;
    text-stroke: 2px transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffeba7;
    text-fill-color: #ffeba7;
    color: #ffeba7;
  }
  .nav ul li a{
    font-size: 8vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>700 Studios - Proyectos</title>
  <link href="proyectos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../logo.ico">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Menú Épico -->
  
    <a href="enlacecensurado" class="logo" target="_blank">
        <img src="../logo.webp" alt="700 logos">
    </a>

    <input class="menu-icon" type="checkbox" id="menu-icon" name="menu-icon"/>
    <label for="menu-icon"></label>
    <nav class="nav">       
        <ul class="pt-5">
            <li><a href="../index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="./proyectos.html">Proyectos</a></li>
            <li><a href="../planes/planes.html">Planes Futuros</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


  

    <div class="section-center">
        <h1 class="mt-5">⬇Nuestros Proyectos⬇</h1>
      <br>
      <br>
        <h3 class="mb-auto">2023</h3>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="videocensurado" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>


        <h3 class="mb-auto">2022</h3>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="videocensurado" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

      
        <h3 class="mb-auto">2021</h3>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="videocensurado" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

      
        <h3 class="mb-auto">2020</h3>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="videocensurado" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

</body>
```

Gracias por adelantado.

(Este post ya lo subí, pero me parece que se eliminó, en el caso de que este duplicado no duden en comunicarmelo).

Comment: Me dijeron que era mejor hacer una nueva y borrar esa. ¿Es así?

Comment: Igual mejor, como me recomendaron, dejo está y borro la otra, ya que la otra tiene 3 votos negativos acumulados.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el primer texto? ¿ _2022_ ? ¿ _2023_ ?

Comment: ¿Este `transform: translateY(-50%);` en _.section_center_ es a propósito?

Comment: Hay un poquito de copy paste jeje ':)

Comment: Si removés esa línea que te mencioné, ¿funciona como querés? No copies por copiar...

Comment: No copio por pegar, veo el código antes y lo intento entender, pero hay algunas que no la entendí, por eso simplemente copie.

De todas formas gracias!! Ahora ya funciona, lo único es que se queda muy abajo el texto, pero eso me parece que ya se como arreglarlo.

Gracias de nuevo.